# Use Lowercase in Jade conditional Statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I wonder how to lowercase the value in the conditional statement within Jade template. The code below produces error:

```
if type.toUpperCase() =="S"
  .name.left=person.fullName         
else
  .name.left=person.shortName
```

Thank you

Comment: You should probably include the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functions in Jade/Pug conditionals doesn't work. It should always be `if myVar == 'myCondition'`

If you want to use functions or other stuff in an jade/pug conditional you should prepare your variables first.
By leading new lines with a minus `-` you are able to write regular JavaScript in JADE / PUG. This gives you a powerfull weapon to resolve almost everything.
For example you want to check an uppercased string against your condition you should do it like this:

```
- var string = 'myString'
- var myUppercaseString = string.toUpperCase()
if myUppercaseString == 'myCondition'
   // Do stuff if condition is met
else
   // Do stuff if condition isn't met
```

In your case it should look something like this:

```
-  var person = {
-    fullName: 'Hans Dieter Müller',
-    shortName: 'Hansi'
-  }
-  var type = 's'
-  var type1 = type.toUpperCase()

if type =="S"
  .name.left=person.fullName         
else
  .name.left=person.shortName

if type1 =="S"
  .name.left=person.fullName         
else
  .name.left=person.shortName
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/oLdVzg